# disable next 3 days in javascript calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I want to disable next 3 days (excluding sunday) in javascript calendar.
Sundays should be disabled as well.

```
 Calendar.setup({
        inputField : '_dob',
        ifFormat : '%m/%e/%y',
        button : '_dob_trig',
        align : 'Bl',
        singleClick : true,
       disableFunc: function(date)
    {
        var mydate= new Date();
        mydate.setDate(mydate.getDate()+1);
        // alert(date+'---'+mydate);
        if(date==mydate)
        {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    });
```

i tried to alert `date` and `mydate` 
`Tue Oct 21 2014 14:40:11 GMT+0530 (IST)---Tue Oct 21 2014 14:40:20 GMT+0530 (IST)`

Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution -

```
    disableFunc: function(date)
    {
        var first_day = new Date();
        var second_day= new Date();
        var third_day= new Date();

        first_day.setDate(first_day.getDate());
        if(first_day.getDay()===0)
        {
             first_day.setDate(first_day.getDate()+1);
        }

        second_day.setDate(first_day.getDate()+1);
        if(second_day.getDay()===0)
        {
            second_day.setDate(first_day.getDate()+2);
        }

        third_day.setDate(second_day.getDate()+1);
        if(third_day.getDay()===0)
        {
            third_day.setDate(second_day.getDate()+2);
        }


        var flag1 = first_day.getDate()===date.getDate() && first_day.getMonth()===date.getMonth() && first_day.getYear()===date.getYear();
        var flag2 = second_day.getDate()===date.getDate() && second_day.getMonth()===date.getMonth() && second_day.getYear()===date.getYear();
        var flag3 = third_day.getDate()===date.getDate() && third_day.getMonth()===date.getMonth() && third_day.getYear()===date.getYear();

        if(date.getDay() === 0 || flag1 || flag2 || flag3)
        {  return true; }
        else
        {  return false; }
    }
});
```